# not able to receive data in providers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I am trying to make a login page using nextjs and spotify js but encountering following error

[image: error encoutered]

Below is the following code

```
import React from 'react'
import { getProviders , signIn } from "next-auth/react"

function Login({ providers }) {
    return (
        <div>
           

            {Object.keys(providers).map((provider) => {
                <button>Login With {provider.name}</button>
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login;


export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const providers = await getProviders()
    
    return {
        props : {
            providers,
        }
    }
}
```

AND below is the code for providers in [...nextauth].js

```
export default NextAuth({
    // Configure one or more authentication providers
    providers: [
        SpotifyProvider({
            clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_SECRET,
            authorization: LOGIN_URL,
        }),
        // ...add more providers here
    ],
})
```

Comment: what actually `const providers` value in getServerSideProps? `console.log(providers)` and  `console.log(typeof(providers))`so I can help you. Also what is the code of `getProviders`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that either you didn't get any providers or your `providers` object is `undefined` on initial render. You can use `Object.keys(providers || {})` instead to make sure it's always an object.

Also, `Object.keys` returns a string array of keys on the object meaning that the `provider` will be a string and won't have a `name` property. If you're iterating over the `Object.keys` you would need to use `providers[provider].name` instead of `provider.name`

Answer (score 0):

How I see it:

```
import React from 'react'
import { getProviders , signIn } from "next-auth/react"

function Login({ providers }) {
    return (
        <div>
           

            {providers.map((provider) => {
                <button>Login With {provider.name}</button>
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login;


export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const providers = await getProviders()
    //check if you have some data here
    console.log(providers)

    return {
        props : {
            providers: providers,
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your nextjs api pointed to current hosting URL.
For example : **http://localhost:3000**. Otherwise it will not work!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).